# I can't use request in firebase emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

Request function isn't working in my firebase emulator and My Firebase CLI version is 11.13.0 that is latest version.

But the screen shot is
'Please update your Firestore Emulator.
This feature requires the latest Firestore Emulator. Please upgrade your Firebase CLI to the latest version and refresh this page.'

I'm not sure how to activate request function in Firebase emulator.

My OS is mac.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem... it's been reported to google as a bug, see [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5051). Workaround for now is to downgrade to firebase-tools@11.11.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed in 11.4.1

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/5081

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v11.14.1